# Django with celery: scheduled task (ETA) executed multiple times in parallel

Tags: django, heroku, celery, django-celery

I'm developing a web application with Django which uses Celery to process asynchronous tasks, especially for transactional emails.

One on my email task is scheduled with the ETA option but it's executed multiple times in parallel resulting in mail chain, very anoying. I can't figure out exactly why. 
I checked twice my Django code and I'm sure that it is publish only one time.

I'm using Redis as a broker/backend result.

My Celery daemon is hosted on Heroku and launched via this command:

```
python manage.py celeryd -E -B --loglevel=INFO
```

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:** I find a valid solution here thanks to a guy on the #celery IRC channel: http://loose-bits.com/2010/10/distributed-task-locking-in-celery.html

Comment: Be sure to read: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html#caveats

Comment: Problem is that I don't know the maximum ETA in my app. I always publish them as soon as I can, even when far in the future (not happen often).. To do that, I should change my app design, to store it in DB and have a crawler to publish them 1 hour before for example..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the [Ensuring a task is only executed one at a time](http://ask.github.com/celery/cookbook/tasks.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time) docs?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I'm checking a similar solution here: http://loose-bits.com/2010/10/distributed-task-locking-in-celery.html leveraging Redis.

It's seems to works pretty well, I customize it a little because I need to block others tasks of the same type AND with the same context.
I hash the task args concatenated with the task function name as a lock key.

I also had to add the wraps decorator from functools since I'm using function-based tasks.